# PHPExcel; Issue with Array from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, session, phpexcel

The website has multiple levels of authority for viewing/editing.

I've been working on a page for a website that gathers information stored in the SQL database and populates an excel template.

application.php contains all the database connections etc.

Basically, the problem I'm having is when I call on the array to populate cells it shows up as duplicates of the same array value.  Not only that, but it crams them all onto the same column.

The Values I would need to populate are:

Part No.    Description   U/Price   Q'ty    Total

15666562003 Lamp Assembly $20.00    1       $20.00

Freight     131514        $12.35    1       $12.35

The data would show up like this:

Part No.   Description   U/Price    Q'ty     Total

Freight Freight 131514 131514 $12.35 $12.35 1 1 $12.35 $12.35

```
<?php

include "./include/application.php";
require './Classes/PHPExcel.php';

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

class CForm extends CApplication
{

function CForm()
{
$this->CApplication();
}

//**********************************************************

function Export($msg = "")
{


if ($_SESSION['aID'] == "" && $_SESSION['mID'] == "237" && $_SESSION['mID'] == "178" &&        $_SESSION['mID'] == "551")
{
    $sWhere = " AND dID = '$_SESSION[mID]'";
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM dl_warranty_claims 
        INNER JOIN dealers ON (dID = wDealerID)
        WHERE 1 ".$sWhere." AND wID = '$_GET[id]'";

$res = $this->SQL($sql);
if (!($row = $this->FetchArray($res)))
{
    print "You do not have access to view this report.";
    exit();
}

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
// Read the template file
 $inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
 $inputFileName = './templates/warrantyclaimtemplate2.xlsx';
 $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
 $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

// Adding data to the template
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A3', ($row['wDealerName']));
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B3', ($row['wID']));
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C3', ($row['wCustomerName']));    
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D3', ($row['wModelName']));
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E3', ($row['wChassisSN']));
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F3', ($row['wEngineSN']));
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G3', ($row['wDateDelivery']));
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H3', ($row['wDateFailure']));
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I3', ($row['wDateClaim']));
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J3', ($row['wOperatingHours']));

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dl_warranty_parts 
            WHERE wpWarrantyClaimID = '$_GET[id]'";
    $res = $this->SQL($sql);
    while($rowp = $this->FetchArray($res))
    {
        $objPHPExcel->getActivesheet()->FromArray($rowp, NULL, 'A4');
    }

// Write and save file
 $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');

 header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-  officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="warrantyclaimreport.xlsx"');

 $objWriter->save('php://output');
}
}


?>
```

Comment: So what's the actual issue? Error messages?

Comment: Note that you should be using the `Excel2007` Readers and Writers for OfficeOpenXML `.xlsx` files; the `Excel5` Reader and Writer are for BIFF-format `.xls` files

Comment: Hello, the issue is that it sends me to a blank page instead of downloading the excel document.

Comment: Also, I've changed the readers and writers and I'm still facing the same issue.  I've also changed the save option to $objWriter->save('php://output');

Answer (score 0):

Your save statement

```
$objWriter->save('WarrantyClaim.xlsx');
```

is writing a file called `WarrantyClaim.xlsx` to disk (in the current working directory of your script).

Yet you have headers aying that you're going to send the output to the browser

Besides sending the correct headers for the filetype that you're writing:

```
Filetype    Writer        Content type    
.xls        Excel5        application/vnd.ms-excel
.xlsx       Excel2007     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

saving to `php://output` will send the file to the browser

You also have a similar issue with your Reader: using the `Excel5` Reader to read a .xlsx file when you should be using the `Excel2007` Reader

Comment: Hi Mark, Thank you for your response!  I applied your changes to my coding, however, it's still not working properly.  I am still being redirected to a blank screen. The edited code is in my original posting.  I was thinking that it could be an error with the PHP Extensions not being enabled properly or that perhaps I had the wrong PHP version.  I'm on version 5.2.0

Comment: PHPExcel should still (currently) work with PHP 5.2 (though I'd certainly recommend an upgrade)

Comment: Try saving to disk and see if the file is correctly generated: if so, then it indicates that the problem is with the write to browser

Comment: Hi Mark, neither is working... however, I did some tweaking and got it to spit out an error message.  It's saying it cannot access the ZipArchive. It's to my understanding this is because the PHP extension isn't enabled properly. Do you know of a simply way to adjust that? Also, I'm looking into upgrading the PHP version... I just have to make sure it won't interfere with anything that's already established on the site.

Comment: Later versions of PHP tend to have php_zip enabled by default; but if you can't enable it for your version 5.2 then PHPExcel does provide a (slower and more memory hungry) alternative that can be enabled using `PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);` before saving

Comment: Now that's out of the way, I'm getting a Fatal Error: Class 'PHPExcel_Writer_' not found in ../dealers/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php on line 141

Comment: You are still calling `$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');` with a valid writer name like `'Excel2007'` aren't you?

Comment: Yes, my exact code is linked up top.  I updated it as we went along.

Comment: As you'll see if you look at the PHPExcel code itself, line 141 of the IOFactory instantiates a classname that has been generated as a string by replacing `{0}` in the array of Writer details (`PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007_{0}`) with the Writer name that you're passing into that call as the second argument `Excel2007` which should give `PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007`. The fact that you're getting `PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007_` without the `{0}` indicates that a replacement is taking place, but with an empty string (the default for that argument) rather than the `Excel2007` value that you're passing in.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your help.  I resolved the issue by upgrading the PHP version to 5.3! Now I'm just working on learning how to input some of my database items into the template. :)

Comment: Now the problem I'm coming up with, I'm trying to populate cells L12-L22 with data from MySQL.  Basically what this will do is, take the part number from a warranty claim form and populate it into the cells... however, most of the time there are multiple part numbers per claim. The code I have edited above will only populate the last part number that is listed on the report into cell L12.  If it's not too strenuous, help would be much appreciated!  I'm sure I can figure it out on my own eventually. :)

Comment: setCellValue() only populates a single cell, not a range of cells: if `$rowp['wpPartNo']` is an array, then you can use the Worksheet's `fromArray()` method to populate data in a number of adjacent cells at the same time

Comment: Is it possible to populate data starting at a cell other than 1? For instance, in the template I'm using.. I'll need to call two separate arrays in order to populate cells L12:L22 and also cells A19:A22.  This would be much simpler to show rather than type! :) It's quite a project, but I plan on using PHPExcel in a number of areas in our website.  Learning the ropes.

Comment: If you're using fromArray() then the cell reference you pass as an argument is the top-left cell of the range, which could be 'L12' or 'A19'... it's just a cell reference to PHPExcel, you're not limited to row 1

Comment: I'm still having issues. :( unfortunately. I hate to bother you so I've been attempting a few different ways to no avail.  Here is the code that I've got... what it is doing is populating the array strangely.  It has multiples of the same field and uses only the last variable in the array.  I have updated my code above in my original post.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I've updated the original post and header with more specific details.

Answer (score 0):

For your latest question, your `$this->FetchArray()` method appears to be returning **both** enumerated **and** associative data... I don't know exactly what the arguments are, but there should be some setting that allows you to specify **either** enumerated **or** associative, or a method call such as `FetchAssoc()` that will specifically return only an associative array